# Trilib runtime import - Can't select object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime

I'm using the Trilib library to import object in runtime into my app. I click the import button I coded, I select the model from a folder in my pc and import it to the scene.

The thing is: I want to select that object to move it or change its scale. The model appears in the scene, but you can't access it.

To do the import im using
`AssetLoaderContext assetLoaderContext = AssetLoader.LoadModelFromFile(filePath);`
and as I said the model appears in screen, seems to be loaded. But `assetLoaderContext` is empty, and any try to access its variables returns an error. It's like it only loads an image.

When doing `Debug.Log(assetLoaderContext.Models.Count);` it returns zero, as if no model was loaded, but it gets created in the hierarchy. I also have coded a PolyCount() function yo count how many polygons are there on screen, and when importing the model it goes up, so i guess it exists.

I tried to attach a tag and a collider to the object, but I can't as it apparently does not exist.

This is part of the code I'm using right now

```
public void ImportModel()
{
    // Open the file selection dialog

    var paths = StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Select 3d model", "", "", false);

    if(paths != null && paths.Length > 0) 
    {
        string filePath = paths[0];
        AssetLoaderContext assetLoaderContext = AssetLoader.LoadModelFromFile(filePath);
        Debug.Log(assetLoaderContext.Models.Count);

        Dictionary<GameObject, TriLibCore.Interfaces.IModel> hiztegi = assetLoaderContext.Models;
        foreach (var keyValuePair in  hiztegi)
        {
            Debug.Log(keyValuePair.Key);
            loadedModel = keyValuePair.Key;
            break;
        }
         

       Debug.Log(loadedModel);
       if(loadedModel != null)
        
       // assign a tag to be able to edit the object
       AssignTag(loadedModel);

       // attach a mesh collider to the model
       AttachMeshCollider(loadedModel);
        
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("failed to find the root gameobject of the loaded object");
        }
    }


}
```

Is it the error on the variables selected when using LoadModelFromFile()?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just had to use the trilib events, using OnLoad solved the problem.